# Is there a way to check if a .msg file has attachments in PHP

Tags: php

i've created a upload system fo uploading emails (.msg) out of outlook (drag and drop).

So my question is if there is a way to check if the uploaded .msg file has file attachment/s. I dont need to get the attachment files only a boolean (true or false)

Comment: You're probably best of using a library specifically made for using this kind of file, such as https://github.com/hfig/MAPI